# Slides of Bootcamp

Tags: development

I need the slides of this bootcamp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0P8JeL3TURU&list=PLilwLeBwGuK6NsYMPP_BlVkeQgff0NwvU&ab_channel=Solana can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [github](https://github.com/solana-developers/pirate-bootcamp/) readme for each lesson includes a link to the slides.

Here's the one for the video you've linked:
https://github.com/solana-developers/pirate-bootcamp/tree/main/quest-1